# MongoDB and SQL benchmark queries

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, benchmarking

I understand there are lot of issues to consider when doing benchmarking between MongoDB and SQL DB's but I am only trying to understand the right query to use in my setup.

Example the equivalent of `SELECT * FROM table` in SQL is `db.collection.find()` in MongoDB.

In calculating the total time taken for each query, must I iterate over the SQL ResultSet and MongoDB Cursor respectively or just executing the query will be enough. Below is my sample iteration steps.

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);
time = getTime()
    while (rs.next()) {}
time1 = getTime()
total = time1-time;
```

My understanding is, if I don't iterate over the Cursor in MongoDB, will that not just return the time taken to process the first batch of results i.e. 20 documents instead of all the matched documents?

Comment: ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString).ToArray() will get all data at once

Comment: In fact, just looping over the resultset without actually querying the data might not be enough. You never know how much magic mumbo-jumbo the driver does in the background to retrieve data on the fly as needed, which you won't cover in a simple looping scenario as shown above. This goes for both databases ;-)

Comment: @mtj if that is the case, then should we worry much about that?

Comment: driver itself could affect performance, especially when you used some mapping features to map records to objects.

Comment: @fanbondi : Yes, definitely. Usually, you query data to actually process the results. What use is a database, which is blazingly fast in returning a lazy loading result set, but then takes a second to read every single field?

Comment: @mtj so I guess what I am not clear about is how MongoDB fetches the rest of the information. Will it send another request to the server for each subsequent Cursor iteration? Or it will just get the data from the Cursor without doing another round trip to the server?

Comment: @fanbondi: Frankly, I don't know how the Mongo driver or *any other* database driver implements it. I just wanted to point out, that your benchmark should take the total read time for both databases, just because this is an unknown and undocumented implementation detail for each and every database driver you compare.

Comment: @mtj to your question, yes driver send another request to server to get another batch with command `getmore` for cursor iteration. However it does use a connection pool to pool all connections.

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding is, if I don't iterate over the Cursor in MongoDB, will that not just return the time taken to process the first batch or results i.e. 20 documents instead of all the matched documents?

you get first batch only because mongo shell help you to do so. a cursor actually won't fetch anything, it just returns at once. so yes you'll have to iterate the mongo cursor, or invoke `toArray()` to get all of them as an `Array`.

You might also want to consider how `normalize` and `denormalize` affects your query. because you also benefit from `denormalized` data schema. with `denormalized` schema, you won't need `JOIN` which forces the hard drive to scan different clusters of disks. Neither does spence joining two records. However `denormalize` is not always an option. So it only makes sense when you have a actual scenario, build queries against that scenario and benchmark those queries.

Comment: @yoaxing, so you mean if I run db.coll.find() MongoDB does not return all the results but instead the first batch and if I type "it" in the shell, then MongoDB will send another request to the server to fetch the more data? or will it just get this data from the Cursor without another round trip to the server?

Comment: @fanbondi I mean, mongo shell would 'type' the first `it` for you, so you can see the first batch. if you assign the cursor to a variable, it doesn't even access the database because nobody's typing the `it` for you.